# Can we identify the "black" faces of a plotted rgl mesh?

Tags: r, mesh, rgl

I have this rgl mesh:

[image]

This mesh comes from an isosurface. The original isosurface has no width, whereas this mesh has a small width.

I have the function `f` defining the isosurface `f=0`, so I can calculate the gradient for each vertex:

```r
library(numDeriv)
normals <- apply(mesh$vb[-4L, ], 2L, function(v) {
  grad(f, v)
})
```

But if I use these normals I get a black "side", because as I said there is a width, so actually both the orange "side" and the black "side" are the same side:

[image]

Theoretically if I reverse the normals for the vertices `v` such that `f(v) < 0`, that would be nice, but because of inexactness there is a couple of black faces if I do that:

```r
ff <- apply(mesh$vb[-4L, ], 2L, f)
normals[, ff < 0] <- -normals[, ff < 0]
mesh$normals <- normals
```

[image]

So I'm wondering: is there a way to identify the faces plotted in black? So that I could reverse the normals for these faces.

Comment: Normals are attached to vertices in meshes, and the triangles or quads recorded in `it` or `ib` define adjacent vertices.  So you could look for a vertex whose normal is very different (approximately opposite) to adjacent ones.

Answer (score 0):

Normals are attached to vertices in meshes, and the triangles or quads recorded in `it` or `ib` define adjacent vertices. So you could look for a vertex whose normal is very different (approximately opposite) to adjacent ones.

Here's an example.  In R, the mesh displays differently than in WebGL, because the WebGL code ignores the direction of the normal.
I've substituted the R display into the output below, but a simpler solution to your original problem might be simply to use the WebGL display instead of the R display.

```r
set.seed(1234)

library(rgl)

# Set up a smooth mesh

mesh <- icosahedron3d(col="red") |> subdivision3d(2) |> addNormals()
str(mesh)
#> List of 4
#>  $ material:List of 1
#>   ..$ color: chr "red"
#>  $ it      : num [1:3, 1:320] 1 43 44 13 45 43 14 44 45 44 ...
#>  $ vb      : num [1:4, 1:162] -1.42e-14 1.01e+03 1.63e+03 2.32e+03 -1.42e-14 ...
#>  $ normals : num [1:4, 1:162] 1.30e-16 5.26e-01 8.51e-01 1.00 -4.47e-18 ...
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "mesh3d"

# Randomly choose two vertices, and flip their normals:

i <- sample(seq_len(ncol(mesh$vb)), 2)
mesh$normals[1:3, i] <- -mesh$normals[1:3, i]

# Show it, but note that rglwidget uses different shading rules, so the
# dark spots won't show up:

open3d()
#> glX 
#>   1
shade3d(mesh)
```

[image: screenshot]

```r
# List all adjacent vertex numbers in a vector
adjacent <- as.numeric(rbind(mesh$it, mesh$it[1, ], NA))

# Extract the normals in Euclidean coordinates
normals <- asEuclidean2(mesh$normals)

# Compute the difference between adjacent normals
normaldiff <- (normals[, adjacent[-1]] 
               - normals[, adjacent[-length(adjacent)]])^2  |>
             colSums() |> 
             sqrt()

# Select the big ones that are not NA
bad <- !is.na(normaldiff) & normaldiff > 1

# Which vertices show up a lot?  
table(adjacent[c(bad, FALSE)])
#> 
#>  23  24  28  78  79  80  83  86  94  95  98 100 102 104 
#>   1   1   6   1   1   6   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

# Which vertices were originally chosen?
i
#> [1] 28 80
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>